# How to show total County using Datetime.Today Filter ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I creating a ticketing tool using .Net MVC. I am stuck at a place where I want to show the Total Count for tickets created for today.

1. Chat Class data type

```
public DateTime? ChatCreateDateTime { get; set; }
```

2. In Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                //Chat dto = new Chat();

                //string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

                ViewBag.todayTicket = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatCreateDateTime == DateTime.Today).Count();

                return View(db.Chats.ToArray().ToList());
            }
                
        }
```

3. In View

```
<p>@ViewBag.todayTicket</p>
```

Data showing is 0 which is wrong, there are 6 tickets added in tool. Created Date also inherits the Time when the button was clicked..

Example Created Date Time = 10/18/2020 02:30 PM and DateTime.Today = 10/18/2020
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ChatCreateDateTime.Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change where expression in this way:

```
ViewBag.todayTicket = db.Chats
    .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime)
        == DateTime.Today)
    .Count();
```

Comment: Not sure that `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` are available in EF Core. I would say that your previous answer was just fine, except that personally I would use `.Value` instead of cassting.

Comment: ViewBag.todayTicket = db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) == DateTime.Today).Count();

Comment: Thank you Saeed and Guru for your suggestions. Helps a lot. I also wanted to know formual to get AHT CreatedDateTime subtract EndDateTime, but how can I get this in action. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
ViewBag.todayTicket = db.Chats
    .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime)
          == DateTime.Today)
    .Count();
```